# Instagram send messege api returning "Please check if IG business connected to FB page correctly" error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, instagram-graph-api

I'm using meta graph api for sending message through instagram DMs. I'm using the page access token for sending the messsage.The api which I used for sending message is

```
curl -i -X POST \
  "https://graph.facebook.com/LATEST-API-VERSION/me/messages?access_token=PAGE-ACCESS-TOKEN" \
  --data 'recipient={"id”:”IGSID”}&message={"text”:”TEXT-OR-LINK”}’
```

The API is returning an error response like

> Please check if IG business connected to FB page correctly. Or check if page token has enough IG permissions granular scopes for IG send api

The permission which I have given for creating the token are

`pages_show_list,instagram_basic,instagram_manage_messages`

Do anyone know why this error message is occuring. Are the permissions which I gave enough for sending the message through instagram DM.

I have tried changing the permissions and reconnecting the instagram business account with the facebook page.

I expected that the API will work and it didn't.